# Pylance giving wrong errors regarding comparison operators and members of modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pylance

1. Pylance doesn't recognize the "socket" module. There's no Intellisense for it and when I write code, I only get squiggly lines on everything I call, even though it's a member of the core python library, isn't it?

[image]

2. Pylance throws errors for simple comparisons like this one, even though I'm only comparing two integers:

[image]

Now I know I could ignore all these errors, but is this a known problem? I did some quick searches, but I wasn't able to find anything other then "this gets fixed in the next version", even though I have a much higher version than that.

I did a restart of VS Code and reinstalled all the extensions multiple times already. Do you know any other possible fixes for this?

The version of the Pylance extension used is v2022.8.40.

VS Code 1.70.2, Python extension v2022.13.12381007, IntelliCode extension v1.2.23

Comment: This might be obvious, but have you tried if it happens only when you use `socket`? Or does it happen with other standard modules too? The could be something wrong with your vscode `settings.json`

Comment: socket is currently the only module that shows this error, I went through like ten different other modules that worked. But I got them from the autocomplete after typing "import" do you maybe have any other modules that I should test?

Comment: Seems to me you are using pre-release version of Python. Maybe you could try to switch back to release version and see if the problem persists?
From the list of installed extensions in your VScode, find Python. From there find the button `Swithc to Release Version` and reload your VScode.

Comment: same issue, I'm not using the pre-release version